# What's the biggest possible loop-de-loop that a car could drive through?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

We're talking vertical loop.

So let's assume the loop structure is hyper strong and not prone to any structural damage.

Going with a fast car's top speed of let's say 350 km/h = (roughly) 100 m/s...

Plugging that into one of the rudimentary centripetal force equations:

\begin{array}{l}
v=\sqrt{g\cdotp r}\\
\\
\frac{v^{2}}{g} =r\\
\\
\end{array}

Solving, we get radius = 1020 m  --- that's a big loop! We're talking about a 2km wide loop, circumference of 6km!

So is this at least theoretically correct? Would this work in real life? Why or why not?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I realize it did sound like a homework question, but I assure you it's not - I'm interested in whether this loop-de-loop would function in the real world, and why... Hope that clears things up.

Comment: @KarensRevenge Just a suggestion tag the person who you intend to reply to like I did here otherwise they won't receive any notification and your comment  would be left unread unless they revisit the question

Comment: Also what I feel is missing is that even if you accelerate the car at full acceleration as it gains height the velocity will decrease as the potential energy increases so the velocity won't remain constant as the power delivered by the engine is constantly at the maximum value, so the radius calculation then is off. You can visit here for the exact calculations- http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/211-sp06/class-energy/looptheloop.html#:~:text=A%20loop%2Dthe%2Dloop%20track,Neglect%20friction.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't think it's really offtopic OP is making a fundamental mistake in assuming the velocity to be constant throughout it doesn't seem a homework question perse but a genuine doubt to me

Comment: @DinoManPhyLab Thanks! Yes that makes sense.

Comment: @KarensRevenge no problem